# How to import Russian character in magento by CSV

Tags: magento, csv

I need to import russian product name by csv ib magento but it is showing "????" like this
with replace of Russian word.

if there is a good solution, it will be good for me.

[image]
thanks

Comment: Make sure you edit the CSV file in UTF-8 character encoding

Answer (score 3):

Magento doesnot allow special Character for importing customer data generally..
For Example In the Dutch translation the special characters do not (always) show up properly. If we have to import some data like jaydéép through csv of magento import it will shows error
so best practice is
Go to .htaccess file and remove # from
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
and
open the your csv file in .txt format and Save As under UTF-8 and then import the data in magento
Your special character will also get import in magento admin without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to replace the character itself with the equivalent HTML code.

For example б  would be imported as `&#1073;`

A list of such codes can be found here:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm

But I'm sure there is a more useful resource out there - but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the language.